# Convert a Cell Matrix to a One Row Vector?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, vector, cell

Say I had this matrix.

```
M = {'My string 1';
        'My string 2';
        'My String 3';}
```

How do I get it to be

```
V = ['My string 1 My string 2 My String 3']
```

Without doing:

```
V = [M{1} M{2} M{3}]
```

(I have a really big matrix and this would take forever)

I can't figure this out.

Comment: Do you really want spaces between the strings? Because `V = [M{1} M{2} M{3}]` doesn't put spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
V = [M{:}];
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure Luis' answer is what you want, but if you need the spaces between the strings as in your manually typed output example, you can use [`strjoin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html) with a space specified as the delimiter:

```
>> V = strjoin(M(:)',' ') % M(:)' ensures a row of cells

V =

My string 1 My string 2 My String 3
```